# python writing a list-of-tuples to a file

Tags: python

I need to write a list to a file in python. I know the list should be converted to a string with the join method, but since I have a tuple I got confused. I tried a lot to change my variables to strings etc, this is one of my first attempts:

```
def perform(text):
    repository = [("","")]
    fdist = nltk.FreqDist(some_variable)
    for c in some_variable:
        repository.append((c, fdist[c]))
    return ' '.join(repository)
```

but it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#120>", line 1, in <module>
    qe = perform(entfile2)
  File "<pyshell#119>", line 14, in perform
    return ' '.join(repository)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, tuple found
```

any ideas how to write the list 'repository' to a file? Thanks!

Comment: you should explain better what is that you want to return, a string of which format? do you want later to retrieve the tuples?

Comment: is the repository supposed to be some kind of persistent cache?

Comment: `repository` is a list-of-tuples, because you specifically created it as a list-of-tuples, by doing `.append((c, fdist[c]))`. If you only wanted a flat list, then only `.append()` one item at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the tuples to strings before passing them to join()

I have fairly drastically rearranged this, such that:

1. your function is now a generator (lower memory requirements)
2. the desired format is passed in - it returns whatever format you ask it to return
3. I am guessing that some_variable is a reportable subset of text?

.

```
def perform(seq, tell=None, fmt=tuple):
    """
    @param seq:  sequence, items to be counted (string counts as sequence of char)
    @param tell: sequence, items to report on
    @param fmt:  function(item,count) formats output
    """
    # count unique items
    fdist = nltk.FreqDist(seq)

    if tell is None:
        # report on all seen items
        for item,num in fdist.iteritems():
            yield fmt(item,num)
    else:
        # report on asked-for items
        for item in tell:
            try:
                yield fmt(item,fdist[item])
            except KeyError:
                # tell contained an item not in seq!
                yield fmt(item,0)

# write to output file
fname = 'c:/mydir/results.txt'
with open(fname, 'w') as outf:
    outf.write(' '.join(perform(text, some_variable, ','.join)))
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to store a dictionary on the disk, use [`shelve`](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html#shelve.DbfilenameShelf):

```
import shelve

def get_repository(filename='repository'):
    # stores it's content on the disk
    store = shelve.DbfilenameShelf(filename)

    if not store: 
        # if it's empty fill it
        print 'creating fdist'
        # fdist = nltk.FreqDist(some_variable)
        fdist = dict(hello='There')
        store.update(fdist)
    return store

print get_repository()
# creating fdist
# {'hello': 'There'}
print get_repository()
# {'hello': 'There'}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should first convert the list of tuples to a list of strings using list comprehension and then after that use the join:

```
list_of_strings = ["(%s,%s)" % c for c in repository]
' '.join(list_of_strings)
```

Comment: @gfar90: When you've received enough answers and tried them out, if one has helped you, be sure to accept it (by clicking the checkmark-shaped icon next to the answer) -- that's fundamental SO etiquette!-)